# Can't wrap Autocomplete's mat-option in a TemplateRef

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have created a component that's basically a wrapper around the Material Autocomplete. I want to be able to take an optional `TemplateRef` as input to the component (`optionTemplate`). If the template is defined, it will override the default template that is used for the autocomplete's `<mat-option>` elements. I use a `ng-container` with a `TemplateOutlet`, but the autocomplete-panel does not show unless i also put a `mat-option` element under `mat-autocomplete`.

Can anyone tell me why this does not work? Is there any way to make it work as intended?

I created [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zbh2i1?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts) StackBlitz which demonstrates the problem.

**autocomplete.component.html**

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input #input matInput type="text" class="form-control" [matAutocomplete]="autocomplete" (input)="valueChanged($event)" [readonly]="readonly"
    (focus)="$event.target.select()" (blur)="onTouched()">
  <mat-autocomplete #autocomplete="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFunction" (optionSelected)="onOptionSelected($event)">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="optionTemplate ? optionTemplate : defaultOptionTemplate; context: { options: filteredOptions }"></ng-container>

    <!-- The autocomplete panel does not show if this line is commented out --->
    <mat-option></mat-option>

  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>

<ng-template #defaultOptionTemplate let-options="options">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
      {{ displayFunction(option) }}
  </mat-option>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Hi andbjer, did u solve the problem for this,If solved Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a bug with Angular Material, since I'm facing the same issue with 8.x version.

I forked your demo and created a bug report https://github.com/angular/components/issues/18353